# IDs in visual flow acting strange

Tags: visual-workflow

In my visual flows I keep getting errors because the IDs used are not the ones I set.

I have lead record with ID equal to 00QU000000el9vN or 00QU000000el9vNMAQ for the case sensitive ID. I set that as the default variable within a flow, no passing in or anything. Then I get an error email and in the email it says that the variable is set to 00QU000000el9nzMAA. It seems to be stuck on this ID even though I'm not using it anymore.

When I put that ID in the URL it tells me record deleted. I've added some screen elements which seem to suggest it is using the correct ID at least part of the way through. So it might just be the error email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was testing a non-active version of the flow. And whenever the flow ends, it repeats automatically WITH THE ACTIVE VERSION OF THE FLOW. The active version still has the error and the old ID as the default value for that variable.